# Shell script to search a string and output lines for specific files in all directories

Tags: string, shell, file, search

How can I search for a string in specific files in all directories and output results to a file?

I am using below code but how can I write a shell script for this?

```
find. -name *.txt | grep *%text* > result.xls
```

Comment: You may prefer `find . -type f -name "*.txt" -execdir grep '*%text*' '{}' + > results.txt`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your point. I think your command line will work fine.
To make this into a script, just save this command line into a text file, and add x permission.

1. Save following content into a file. Ex: xxx.sh

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   find . -name '*.txt' | grep '*%text*' > result.xls
   ```
2. Add x permission for the file by following command.

   ```
   chmod +x xxx.sh
   ```
3. Run the script.

   ```
   ./xxx.sh
   ```
4. Check this output file `result.xls`.